# How to get user purchases from Play Store in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I am trying to use [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) Flutter package to implement paid version of my app. This should turn off ads.

I don't want to listen for purchases as it seems like an unnecessary overhead for my very simple app.

[Google Play Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#fetch) has `queryPurchasesAsync` method. Is it possible to do this from Flutter, either with `in_app_purchases` package or some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be possible within `in_app_purchase` package: [`InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition.queryPastPurchases`](https://pub.dev/documentation/in_app_purchase_android/latest/in_app_purchase_android/InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition/queryPastPurchases.html)

Usage:

```dart
final addition = InAppPurchase.instance.getPlatformAddition<InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition>();
final purchases = await addition.queryPastPurchases();
```

Comment: Had to add in_app_purchase_android package to dependencies to get it to work. thanks!